# Android license status unknown. Try re-installing or updating your Android SDK Manager. Android sdkmanager tool not found

Tags: android, flutter, android-sdk-manager

I'm installing Android SDK for the first time on Windows 10. Facing problem with sdkmanager tool. Looked up several threads for solution, but to no avail.

`C:\Users\vboppa>flutter doctor -v`

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.20.2, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.959], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 1.20.2 at C:\Boppa\myStuff\flutter
    • Framework revision bbfbf1770c (3 weeks ago), 2020-08-13 08:33:09 -0700
    • Engine revision 9d5b21729f
    • Dart version 2.9.1

[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\vboppa\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.2
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)
    X Android license status unknown.
      Try re-installing or updating your Android SDK Manager.
      See https://developer.android.com/studio/#downloads or visit https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for detailed instructions.

[!] Android Studio (version 4.0)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    X Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    X Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)

[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 3 categories.
```

When I tried to verify Android licenses, the following was the output.

`C:\Users\vboppa>flutter doctor --android-licenses`

```
Android sdkmanager tool not found (C:\Users\vboppa\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\bin\sdkmanager).
Try re-installing or updating your Android SDK,
visit https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for detailed instructions.
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to install Android Studio

A quote from Flutter documentation https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup

> Flutter relies on a full installation of Android Studio to supply its Android platform dependencies